# Using abstract base class in django admin interface with neo4django

Tags: django, neo4j, neo4django

I'm trying to use a simple abstract base class in django's admin interface with neo4django.

Example models.py

```
from neo4django.db import models

class Parent(models.NodeModel):
    name = models.StringProperty()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Example admin.py:

```
from neo4django import admin
from core.models import Child

class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Child, ChildAdmin)
```

The 'name' field doesn't appear in the admin interface.

If I use the same basic structure, but with django.db instead of neo4django.db, it all works fine. Anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

**Update from comments:**

- This has been tried with django 1.5.5 and 1.5.4
- The neo4django version is from the github repo
- Registering the model with or without a ModelAdmin have both been tried and made no difference

Comment: have deleted my answer since I misread what was in the github issue

Comment: What version on `neo4django` are you using. If using the pip package then switch to the git package `pip install -e git+https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/#egg=neo4django-dev` or better fork the project and use your own repo.Also, Django 1.6+ is not yet supported, and as I far as I remember there are some issues with the admin, after the development moved to support Django 1.5.

Comment: I'm using django 1.5.5 and the github package of neo4django

Comment: I will try to investigate your issue and come with an answer, until then, I recommend raising an issue to Github.

Comment: I've created an issue on Github - https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/240

Comment: I've also tried downgrading to django 1.5.4, but that showed the same behaviour

Comment: Does anyone found a solution. I'm using Django 1.7 and facing the same issue...

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried just registering the model, without the `ModelAdmin`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Same result, I'm afraid